# Flutter - My animation is only playing once

Tags: ios, flutter, animation, dart, callback

I wanted to animate text and I put a nice animation. So I've made a statefull widget called AnimatedText() and I use it in an other stateful widget that use this AnimatedText and refresh the text every time you clic the screen. However, when I change this text with a setState(), the animation doesn't play again if it had already played...

Here is my code, the AnimatedText() :

```dart
class AnimatedText extends StatefulWidget {
  double textSize;
  String text;

  AnimatedText(this.text, {this.textSize = 20});

  @override
  _AnimatedTextState createState() => _AnimatedTextState();
}

class _AnimatedTextState extends State<AnimatedText> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _fontSizeAnimation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), vsync: this);
    _fontSizeAnimation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceOut);
    _fontSizeAnimation.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.text, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.white, fontSize: _fontSizeAnimation.value*ResponsiveSize().responsiveSizeSmall(widget.textSize)));
  }
}
```

And here is the class that use the AnimatedText():

```dart
class BasicDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  Question question;
  VoidCallback onTap;
  VoidCallback onPressed;
  BasicDisplay(this.question, this.onTap, this.onPressed);

  @override
  _BasicDisplayState createState() => _BasicDisplayState();
}

class _BasicDisplayState extends State<BasicDisplay> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GamePageBackground(
      onTap: widget.onTap,
      question: widget.question,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: widget.onPressed,
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Color(0xaaffffff), size: ResponsiveSize().responsiveSize(quitIconButtonSize),),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedText(widget.question.category, textSize: questionCategoryTextSize,),
        AnimatedText(widget.question.question, textSize: questionTextSize,),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: ResponsiveSize().responsiveSize(10)),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(widget.question.explanation, textAlign: TextAlign.center ,style: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.white, fontSize: ResponsiveSize().responsiveSize(bottomExplanationTextSize))),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The `onPressed` call back call the Game class that will refresh the text.

Any one know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on @HBS idea !

I took his function and changed it a little bit :

```dart
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedText oldWidget) {
    if(oldWidget.text != widget.text) {
      _controller.reset();
      _controller.forward();
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

Comment: I swear I wrote that first then for some reason changed it to repeat() lol! Glad you solved it!

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `didUpdateWidget` in your `AnimatedText` class:

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(AnimatedText oldWidget) {
  if(oldWidget.text != widget.text) {
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward();
  }
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but it doesn't work. The animation repeats endlessly even if the text is already loaded... It might be because there's two AnimatedText in the same time on the same page on every setState() ?